# How to edit source code for a maven dependency?

Tags: java, spring, maven

I have a java project that includes a dependency using maven. With IntellyJ I can download and read the source code of this dependency, but I cannot change it.

I'm aware that any changes made to the dependency would be lost if not sent to the original repo. The changes would made only for debug/learning purpose.

Can I instruct maven to build the JAR dependency using the source code from a local path?

thanks.

Comment: Yes - go to GitHub, check out the dependency. Hope that it builds and that mainline isn’t too far from the version you’re using. Then build the project and publish it to your local maven repo - bear in mind this dependency might be built with anything from Ant to Gradle - i.e. not necessarily Maven!

Comment: thanks, your comment pointed me on the right direction.  For next readers: The ~/.m2 folder is the local repository. If the dependency is also a maven repository, a simple "mvn install" of the (modified) dependency will compile the JAR and put into the local repository.